# Tomcat 8 seems starting but isn't on Eclipse Neon

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Tomcat 8 not starting properly in Eclipse Neon.

it is starting fine on command Prompt.

when I start it on Eclipse, everything seems ok, i'm getting the final line

> INFO: server startup in 314 ms

and no errors, not even warnings. however, the call to `localhost:8080` is giving a 404 error.

there are no other tomcat instances running on any other port(s). 
there are no projects on Tomcat.

I tried this on different workspaces. I even tried downloading a brand new Tomcat 8 into a separate directory on my disk and installed that server on Eclipse, and got the same thing.

Why does this happen, how to fix this??

all indicates that some server-related setting is messed up on Eclipse, across all workspaces. does this happen? how to fix it, which Eclipse configuration??

"start-up in 314 ms" looks a bit too quick to me(/) I wasn't so careful with the start-up time before, but I don't recall seeing anything tomcat startup faster than 1sec

Ate my whole afternoon in various scales!

TIA

I'm doing these on windows 10, eclipse Neon, Tomcat 8.

Comment: Are you that 8080 is the right port? and have you tried to start tomcat outside of eclipse, from the bin directory?

Comment: @Quakecore yes. didn't change the default port and no other Tomcat instances are running on the machine. it's finding Tomcat, but not bringing that Tomcat default page. giving the 404 error. and the very same Tomcat is being invoked fine from command line

Comment: What apps are deployed on this tomcat?

Comment: @QuakeCore I'm doing a Vaadin 7 project on Maven. I had that the last time it was working. there aren't many apps on it yet, plain java, jersey, jdom and the like. I had two vaadin projects on Tomcat and running at the same time. it starting going wrong from there. now, tomcat is this when no projects on it!

Comment: Could you make sure that manager, Root, ... apps are deployed?

Comment: @QuakeCore how do I do that?

Comment: Check tomcat8/webapps directory, you should find a folder for each webapp.

Comment: @QuakeCore there isn't anything there. this is happening on a new tomcat installation as well. I now have Tomcat 8.0.36 and Tomcat 8.0.36. installed .38 just to try it out, and thre's never been anything deployed on it! didn't get your Q before

Comment: @QuakeCore its about an eclipse setting. but don't know which, where

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127224/discussion-between-quakecore-and-roam).

Answer (score 0):

windows was blocking it. went into the system and saw some failed updates-- must be it.